# Android Studio IDE v4.0 project files not clickable/missing toolbar

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, android-ide

I am facing an annoying bug in the newest Android Studio IDE (v4.0)
After the IDE restart(simple restart or after the PC restart, I can find any 100% case to reproduce this bug) sometimes AS starts and opens the project with such bugs:

1. Project structure becomes collapsed or hidden
2. Project files are NOT clickable in any case, so I can't close or open any files
3. Studio shortcuts do not work at all
4. The top toolbar is missing. (But still, it is shown as enabled in the "View" dropdown menu)
5. Some AS windows do not open. (For example, I am not able to open "Check For Updates" window)

I tried invalidating caches/restart option, but it makes no sense. The only solution is to delete AS studio(Without or with deleting of the settings), then install the older version of AS and make an update to the latest version of the AS.

If I try to simply delete AS and then install the latest 4.0 version, it will have the same bugs as were before the reinstall. If I want to install 4.0 studio without and older version-update routine, than I need to delete all the AS user settings.

What a hell is going on? Someone else facing this issue? Is there is a workaround for this annoying bug?

AS details:

```
Android Studio 4.0
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1237M
Cores: 16
Registry: ide.new.welcome.screen.force=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.kotlin
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check if there are any exceptions in idea.log (Help | Show Log in ... action). Could be a broken installation. Then try to re-install it into a new empty directory.

Answer (score 0):

delete C:\Users{username}.AndroidStudio4.0 folder then try to open the android studio you will re install all the configuration and file support for android studio